# ForEach Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, cisco

I'm trying to make a request to the **AccessPointsDetails** endpoint of the Cisco Prime API and then loop through that to get all URL objects for the AccessPoints so I can get data on each of them.

I get the following output:

```
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3373245; $=3373245}
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3413720; $=3413720}
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3432295; $=3432295}
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3432310; $=3432310}
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3462672; $=3462672}
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3497980; $=3497980}
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3497993; $=3497993}
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3512621; $=3512621}
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3526872; $=3526872}
VERBOSE: Making request to: @{@type=AccessPointDetails; @url=https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/16162527426; $=16162527426}
@type              @url                                                            $          
-----              ----                                                            -          
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3373245     3373245    
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3413720     3413720    
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3432295     3432295    
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3432310     3432310    
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3462672     3462672    
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3497980     3497980    
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3497993     3497993    
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3512621     3512621    
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3526872     3526872    
AccessPointDetails https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/16162527426 16162527426
```

Here is the response JSON for one store as well:

```
{
  "queryResponse": {
    "@last": 9,
    "@first": 0,
    "@count": 10,
    "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
    "@requestUrl": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails?.group=0026",
    "@responseType": "listEntityIds",
    "@rootUrl": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data",
    "entityId": [
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3373245",
        "$": "3373245"
      },
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3413720",
        "$": "3413720"
      },
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3432295",
        "$": "3432295"
      },
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3432310",
        "$": "3432310"
      },
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3462672",
        "$": "3462672"
      },
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3497980",
        "$": "3497980"
      },
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3497993",
        "$": "3497993"
      },
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3512621",
        "$": "3512621"
      },
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3526872",
        "$": "3526872"
      },
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/16162527426",
        "$": "16162527426"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I feel I may be a bit burnt and making a silly oversight?

**Solution Code (See Accepted Answer):**

```
Function allAP {
Write-Verbose "Getting all APs for Store $Store"
$storeApReq = "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails.json?.group=$Store"
Write-Verbose "Making request to $storeApReq"
$Global:apIdListReq = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $storeApReq -method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
$Global:apIdList =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
$Global:apIdCount =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse."@count"

Write-Verbose "Found $siteAPCount APs in Sites Database. $apIdCount out of $siteAPCount APs found."
Write-Verbose "Response Received: $apIdList"
$Global:apIdURL =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
$Global:apURL = $apIdUrl.'@url'

Write-Verbose "Starting a loop."
ForEach($apIdURL in $apIdList) {
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $apURL -method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
Write-Verbose "Making request to: $apURL"
$apURL

}
}
```

Comment: Your `@url` key is returning *another* hashtable, so you need to go a level deeper it appears.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 how might I do that? Let me post the response JSON fast, because I'm not sure I can go a level deeper.

Comment: Here:`$Global:apIdURL =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId."@url"`.  In your `foreach` accessing `apIdURL`, do `$apIdURL['@url']` to access the correct member.

Comment: I'm just getting 10 lines of blank response with that.

Comment: Your question doesn't match what code you're actually running then..  Are you converting the JSON returned from `Invoke-RestMethod` somehow?

Comment: I am not. The function listed here is the extent of this entire request. Only variable outside the scope is ```$Store```.

Comment: Scratch my last comment.  I didn't realize you were getting a `pscustomobject` instead of `hashtable`.  You'll need to do `$apIdURL.'@url'` instead.

Comment: Interesting, still seeing some issues but just need to rework some things. Why the redundancy? This makes the URL actually nested at ```entityId."@url".'@url'``` which doesn't seem right.

Scratch that. I see my mistake. I was the one who created redundancy and confused myself.

Comment: Which version of powershell are you on?  If v2, you don't have access to automatic enumeration which is what your code is attempting to do, but appears to be failing.  I'll post an answer with a write-up of your issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue you're having is accessing the members of your returned object incorrectly.  The `Invoke-RestMethod` is returning a `pscustomobject` representation of the JSON the application returns to you.  Your example JSON looked like this:

```
{
  "queryResponse": {
    "@last": 9,
    "@first": 0,
    "@count": 10,
    "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
    "@requestUrl": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails?.group=0026",
    "@responseType": "listEntityIds",
    "@rootUrl": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data",
    "entityId": [
      {
        "@type": "AccessPointDetails",
        "@url": "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3373245",
        "$": "3373245"
      },

      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

This gets transformed into `pscustomobject`:

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    'queryResponse' = [pscustomobject]@{
        '@last'         = 9
        '@first'        = 0
        '@count'        = 10
        '@type'         = 'AccessPointDetails'
        '@requestUrl'   = 'https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails?.group=0026'
        '@responseType' = 'listEntityIds'
        '@rootUrl'      = 'https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data'
        'entityId'      = @(
            [pscustomobject]@{
                '@type' = 'AccessPointDetails'
                '@url'  = 'https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/3373245'
                '$'     = '3373245'
            }

            ...
        )
    }
}
```

I'm unsure why accessing `.'@url'` isn't working for you.  Below is a working implementation of what you're trying to do.

---

```
function Get-AccessPoint
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        $Store
    )

    # function is accessing above-scope variables $auth and $siteAPCount

    Write-Verbose "Retrieving APs for store $Store"
    $uri = "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails.json?.group=$Store"
    Write-Verbose "Request: $uri"
    $global:apIdListReq = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -ContentType application/json -Headers @{Authorization = $auth}
    $global:apIdList = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
    $global:apIdCount = $apIdListReq.'@count'

    Write-Verbose "Found $siteAPCount APs in Sites Database. $apIdCount out of $siteAPCount APs found."
    foreach ($entity in $apIdList)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Making request to $($entity.'@url')"
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $entity.'@url' -ContentType application/json -Headers @{Authorization = $auth}
    }
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason I can't make ```$apIdURL = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId.'@url'```, I have to create another variable to add the ```'@url'``` which I'm looking for a good explanation. All working now, thank you!

Comment: @CodeSpent You should be able to do `$apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId | ForEach-Object -MemberName '@url'` for that.

Comment: ```-MemberName``` was the operator I was looking for, awesome. Would it be unwise to invoke the request using this or should I create a separate loop?

Comment: @CodeSpent `Invoke-RestMethod` does not take an array of `uri` objects as a parameter so you'll still need to loop to run the request against all the endpoints.

Comment: @CodeSpent So I missed something critical in your code.  You're populating the `URL` list properly, but then you're overwriting it by looking at the original `entityId` object again.  `Invoke-RestMethod` is a v3+ cmdlet, so you do have automatic enumeration, it's just a logic issue in your code.

Comment: Yeah I caught that when I said about creating my own redundancy.